# Object not found if its a user input

Tags: python, praw

```
search_type = str(input("Enter search paramiter. (type top for top of all time) (type hot for populour posts in the last 24 hours) (type new for the newest posts): "))

    hot_apex = subred.search_type(limit=num)
```

I would like search_type to be from a user input so the user could write top and then search type = top
and changes to

```
hot_apex = subred.top(limit=num)
```

However, I get this error message 'Subreddit' object has no attribute 'search_type' however top is a object of subreddit

Comment: Use `if...elif...else` or `getattr()`

Comment: I don't understand sorry can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`search_type` is a variable defined as a string.

`subred.search_type` tries to look for an *attribute* called `"search_type"` in the `subred` object. It **doesn't** resolve the *variable* `search_type` and look for an attribute named by the *value of that variable*. To do that, you need to use the `getattr()` function.

```
search_type = input("Enter type: ")
try:
    func_to_call = getattr(subred, search_type)
    results = func_to_call(limit=num)
except AttributeError:
    print("Invalid input")
    results = []
```

Alternatively, you could use an `if..elif` ladder, but this can quickly get cumbersome if you have many possible valid inputs:

```
if search_type == "hot":
    results = subred.hot(limit=num)
elif search_type == "top":
    results = subred.top(limit=num)
else:
    print("Invalid input")
    results = []
```

Comment: No, you would just put an else to catch all errors and return the specific error. But you are right, getattr does have `AttributeError` exception.

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional statements:

```
search_type = str(input("Enter search paramiter. (type top for top of all time) (type hot for populour posts in the last 24 hours) (type new for the newest posts): "))

if search_type == "top"
    hot_apex = subred.top(limit=num)
elif search_type == "hot":
    hot_apex = subred.hot(limit=num)
else:
    #return error
```